# Brainfuck with 1bit memory cells?

Tags: binary, brainfuck, turing-complete, esoteric-languages

Would an implementation of the programming language Brainfuck, still be turing complete if its memory cells were 1bit in capacity, instead of the usual 8bit?

The + and - instructions become identical, however this need not be a problem.

I see no issue with, for example 4bit memory cells, but I cannot work out if this scales all the way to single bit values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the resulting language would still be Turing-complete. In fact, several such languages exist. One of them is [Boolfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Boolfuck). It does exactly what you suggest: have each cell be a single bit and get rid of `-`, because it's redundant. It also uses `;` instead `.` for output. [The official website](http://samuelhughes.com/boof/) contains a reduction from Brainfuck to Boolfuck which proves Boolfuck's Turing-completeness. I'm reiterating the reduction here to make the answer self-contained:

```
Brain.  Bool.
+       >[>]+<[+<]>>>>>>>>>[+]<<<<<<<<<
-       >>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<+[>+]<[<]>>>>>>>>>[+]<<<<<<<<<
<       <<<<<<<<<
>       >>>>>>>>>
,       >,>,>,>,>,>,>,>,<<<<<<<<
.       >;>;>;>;>;>;>;>;<<<<<<<<
[       >>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<+[>+]<[<]>>>>>>>>>[+<<<<<<<<[>]+<[+<]
]       >>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<+[>+]<[<]>>>>>>>>>]<[+<]
```

Other bit-based Brainfuck-derivatives include [Smallfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Smallfuck) and [BitChanger](http://esolangs.org/wiki/BitChanger). [This article](http://esolangs.org/wiki/BF_instruction_minimalization) may also be of interest to you, which goes through several steps of minimising the Brainfuck language by removing redundancy (including using bits instead of bytes).